# Wyh Is a subprocess call to python not using the python interpreter the calling script was executed in?

Tags: python, subprocess, virtualenv

I am trying to run python code on a build server. In order to keep the agent clean, I'm creating a virutal environment which can be deleted after the task. The python script calls python via subprocess. The Questions are:

1. why does the call to subprocess not use the same python virtual env the actual script was called in?
2. How can this be achieved?

Miminal example:

tmp.py:

```
from subprocess import check_output
import sys

# python interpreter used to call this script
print(sys.executable)
# check which python interpreter is used when calling subprocess
print(check_output(f'python -c "import sys\nprint(sys.executable)').decode())
```

run.bat:

```
@echo off

python -m venv .\test_venv
call .\test_venv\Scripts\activate.bat

python tmp.py
```

output, where the second line is the default python installation on my computer:

```
λ run.bat
D:\tmp\pytest\test_venv\Scripts\python.exe
D:\tools\python\python.exe
```

desired output:

```
λ run.bat
D:\tmp\pytest\test_venv\Scripts\python.exe
D:\tmp\pytest\test_venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

I am on 64 bit Windows 10.

Comment: My understanding is that when you run ```check_output```, it 'creates' a new process using a default path environment which happens to have the d:\tools\python in the path.  If I remember correctly, you can pass the running environment into check_output using ```env=...```. so you pass the current os.environ to that env parameter..

Answer (score 1):

The `subprocess` you create uses the operating system's general `PATH` traversal to find and run the commands you specify, and doesn't know anything about the parent process.

You already know the value of `sys.executable`; if that's specifically what you want to run, say so:

```
print(check_output([sys.executable, "-c", "import sys\nprint(sys.executable)"]), text=True)
```

(This also avoids the shell, which was providing no value at all. Without an explicit `shell=True`, your code would only work on Windows.)

(Conversely, on any sane platform, the environment, including the virtual environment, *would* be inherited by child processes.)

However, Python calling Python is almost always an antipattern. Instead, you want to refactor the code so you can `import` it and run it in the same process.